# about the coordinator design pattern in larman?

Tags: design-patterns

I was reading the 1st edition of UML and patterns from larman and in chapter 22.11 it talks about the coordinator pattern. i just understand that is an object that is between the view and the controller but i didnt understand why it is needed and when to use it. can someone explain to me how does this pattern works? maybe a simple code example.also is it the same than delegator?

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What topics can I ask about here?

a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
what typesof questions should i avoid asking?

If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)
ask good 
Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include som.

Comment: i dont know what i did wrong in my question please tell me if the question is really off topic. thanks for reading my post.